# Why doesn't "try, except" work with classic "open(fname, 'r')" in python?

Tags: python, file, exception

I have a function that opens a file and returns an opened `file` object.

```
def read_any():
    try:
        opened = gzip.open(fname, 'r')
    except IOError:
        opened = open(fname, 'r')
    return opened
```

When I attempt to run this function on some non-zipped file `except` condition does not get triggered and the function crashes with the message: `IOError: Not a gzipped file`.

Ok, now I try and do the same with `with` statement:

```
def read_any2():
    try:
        with gzip.open(fname, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()
    except IOError:
        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
            return f.read()
```

Now, if I try to run the **same** file the function works as intended.
Can you explain why doesn't `except` condition get triggered?

Comment: The IOError gets raised not when the file object is created, but upon the first read.

Comment: I don't understand. I assume that whatever is wrapped by `try`, `except` should be handled accordingly.

Comment: In the second example, you call `.read()` inside the try-except block. Change the first example to `return opened.read()` in both blocks to see what's going on.

Comment: I changed, `exception` gets triggered but I don't *see* what's is going on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what's going on, test it in a REPL:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> f = gzip.open('some_nongzipped_file', 'r')
```

You will see that this doesn't raise an error. Once you, however, read from the object:

```
>>> f.read()
... (snip)
OSError: Not a gzipped file
```

, it raises the error.

In short: Simply creating the file object doesn't read anything from the file yet, and thus doesn't know if it should fail or not.

Since in the first example you just return the file object, when you try to read from it later it will raise the exception there (outside your raise-except block). In your second example you return `f.read()` which reads and therefore raises the exception. It has nothing to do with the with block, as you can see if you remove it:

```
def read_any_mod():
    try:
        opened = gzip.open(fname, 'r')
        return opened.read()
    except IOError:
        opened = open(fname, 'r')
        return opened.read()
```

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Makes sense.